# How do I make my progress bar run when the "START" button is clicked?

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface, cmd

I am currently trying to insert a progress bar into my java gui. However, when I click on the "START" button, the progress bar does not run. All the different batch files running in the cmd has to finish then the progress bar runs. But what's the point? I want it to run when the "START" button is pressed and when all the different batch files running in the cmd ends, the progress bar stops too.

Here's my code:

```
JLabel ProgressBar = new JLabel("Progress Bar: ");
ProgressBar.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
ProgressBar.setBounds(100, 285, 180, 53);
contentPane.add(ProgressBar);
final JProgressBar aJProgressBar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
aJProgressBar.setBounds(185,305,184,15);
contentPane.add(aJProgressBar);

//when start button is selected
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
    {
        //the process starts
        JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

        //the progress bar should show it running (by right)
        aJProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        try 
        {
            //create new process    
            String command = "cmd /c start /wait" +DetectDrive+"\\starting.bat";

            //run process
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            //cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
            p.waitFor();
        } 
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        ......

        Date newDate = new Date();
        JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(newDate));

        //the progress bar should stop running (by right)
        //aJProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    }
});
```

So by right... The startTime should show and the progress bar should be running when the "START" button is clicked. However, only when all the batch files in the cmd finishes running then startTime will show.

But for now, the Progress Bar is my priority. How can I make it that when the "START" button is clicked, the progress bar runs and when all finish, then the progress bar stops?

Any help given will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Error do you know how to do this? Desperately looking for an answer to solve it directly

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same thread for updating the `JProgressBar` and to run the script. Problem is that you wait for the `Process` to terminate (`p.waitFor()`), therefore, the thread will wait and not update the `JProgressBar`. The correct solution is to use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) . But I think you could have the thing running by starting a new `Thread` to run your srcipt.

Something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
{
    //the process starts
    JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

    //the progress bar should show it running (by right)
    aJProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    new Thread()
    {
    public void run()
    {
    try 
    {
        //create new process    
        String command = "cmd /c start /wait" +DetectDrive+"\\starting.bat";

        //run process
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        //cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
        p.waitFor();
    } 
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }.start();   

    ......

    Date newDate = new Date();
    JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(newDate));

    //the progress bar should stop running (by right)
    //aJProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
}
```

Comment: this instead, shows the startTime and endTime together when the process has not even finished. and then the `aJProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);` is uncommented, by right, it should run. but then it does not. But if it is commented, the progress bar is able to run when the "START" button is clicked. but does not stop when the process ends.

Comment: Yes, this code does not monitor the end of the `Process` thread. If you want to do that, you will have to use synchronization mechanism. But I really advise you to use SwingWorker instead.

Comment: But do you know how to change to swingWorker? because in my coding, i have so many coding that i don't know how to change it to swingworker